# Construct identity (e => e) at run time as expression tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, expression-trees

I need to create identity expression tree at run-time that just returns the parameter that it receives.

At compile time I could use the lambda `e => e` as expression tree, but I need that transformation at run-time. I'm looking for code similar to how expression tree for `num => num < 5` is constructed in MSDN [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) article.

Answer (score 4):

This will do it:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "e");
var body = param;
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(body, param);
```

Output of `lambda.ToString()`:

```
e => e
```

Note that you need to give `e` a type (in this case it's an int).

---

Pre-edit note:

What you've written (`e => e`) is actually already an expression tree (if defined as an `Expression<T>`, that is). However, it's likely you're wanting to use the factory methods to build the tree.

Answer (score 1):

`e => e`. That's it.

It will need to be typed, of course, so e.g. `Expression<Func<int, int>> intTree = e => e;` for ints, `Expression<Func<string, string>> stringTree = e => e;` for strings, and so on.

Now you've got the tree from the lambda, you can examine it or do whatever else you want the tree for:

```
Console.WriteLine(intTree.Parameters[0].Name); // "e"
Console.WriteLine(intTree.CanReduce); // false
Func<int, int> intIdentityFunction = intTree.Compile();
```